# The password field is not reset/cleared after using remember me, it retaining there eventhough we didnt click remember me

Tags: php, html, session-cookies

I was creating a login form using session, and "remember me" using cookies. The "remember me" function works perfectly for me.When i check "remember me" and login in, after logging out ,i logged in with another username and password without checking "remember me". But the password of previously logged in user is still there in textbox, i want to remove that.

How can i do that? Its still there even after destroying section in logout page.

```
if($user)
     {
            $_SESSION["id"]= $user["rid"];

            if(!empty($_POST["remember"])) 
            {
                setcookie ("usname",$_POST["uname"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                setcookie ("password",$_POST["password"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
            } else
             {
                if(isset($_COOKIE["usname"])) 
                {
                    setcookie ("usname","");
                }
                if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])) 
                {
                    setcookie ("password","");
                }
            }
    } 

    else
     {
        $message = "Incorrect Password or Username";
    }
}
?>  


Here the next part of the code: 

<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION["id"])) 
{ ?>

    <br><br><center><b>Login</b></center><br>
    <form action="" method="post" id="frmLogin"align="center">

    Username:<br>
     <input name="uname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["usname"])) { echo $_COOKIE["usname"]; } ?>" ><br>

    Password:<br>
        <input name="password" type="password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["password"]; } ?>"> <br><Br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> <?php } ?> />
    Remember me<br><br>

<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>  <br><br>

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
<input type="reset">      
</form>
```

Comment: you need to destroy the session and cookies on logout.

Comment: i did that ... i did destroy the section

Comment: Don't store passwords in cookies, it's dangerous. Did you start the session in all the files?

Comment: yeaahh its not securee.......

Comment: I'm just learning php .... i got remember code in onine,,.. so i was apllying that

Comment: Please, ignore anything you read online that suggests saving passwords in cookies. Reading code like this gives me anxiety!

Comment: What are you hoping this will do? `<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> <?php } ?>` ?  I don't see the session being started.  Please show your logout code.

Comment: i didn't include whole code.... its on top.. i didnt include that part

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to  clear the saved passwords in your browser? >> Manage passwords

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).